# key and values in php

Tags: php, arrays

it's been a while since I'm looking for something, I'm blocked for some time to know how to take keys from a value in a php array.

Here is my array where I start my research :

```
[It] => z
[is] => h
[soon] => y
[the] => c
[new] => w
[year] => e
[2017] => e
[!] => e
```

Starting with the value « y », I would like to get the words from another table from this same value than the key [soon] (= "y"), until time is reached this same value.

Here is an exemple of the other array :

```
[Here] => a
[is] => y
[my] => c
[favorite] => u
[team] => y
[.] => o
```

Here are the words than I would like to get from this sentence put in a array of my example :

```
is
my
favorite
```

I tried in many ways, for example with an "in_array" but without success...

Thank you so much to the person which will respond !

Comment: Hello, If I correctly understand ... If you search for `c` you want the output `my favorite team` . Same for `a` => `here is my favorite team.` (because there is no other iteration of `a`)

Comment: How do you want to create that sentence, on what condition rather? It seems pretty unclear on first sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you're somehow finding the **'y' character** from first array, and then filtering out the keys from second array whose values start and end with y.

Assuming you already know the search parameter(i.e y), try the following:

```
$array2 = array(
  'Here' => 'a',
  'is' => 'y',
  'my' => 'c',
  'favorite' => 'u',
  'team' => 'y',
  '.' => 'o'
);

$search = 'y'; // Search parameter
$freq = 0;     // Frequency of 'y' in second array
$result = array();
foreach ($array2 as $k => $arr) {
    if ($arr == 'y') {
        $freq++;         // Increment every time y appears
    }
    /* If only one y appears, store the array keys in $result */
    if ($freq == 1) {
        $result[] = $k;  
    }
    /* If another y appears, break out from the loop such that $result stores all $array2 keys until the second y appears */
    if ($freq == 2) {
        break;           
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => is
  [1] => my
  [2] => favorite
)
```